# Which websites can be used to trade minifigures?

Tags: minifigures, shopping

Are there any reliable websites that do minifigure trading? I had a look around but couldn’t find much at all.

Comment: Hi Morgan and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help] pages to learn more about how this site operates, what can you expect and what is expected of you in return. Have a nice day - don't forget to respond to comments and rate and mark any helpful answers. Have a nice stay!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a site for explicitly this purpose, called aptly [swapfig.com](https://swapfig.com).

It works by connecting other users either via a wanted or an offered ad, and if the other party accepts the trade you have to exchange postal info and send the minifigure. When the minifigure is received you have to check a box in the trade process page and you can leave a comment. Same if the item is never received. Like Bricklink, building a good reputation is necessary if you want to be trusted in making exchanges.

---

Or if by trading, you mean buying and selling, then there are many suitable websites:

- [brickscout.com](https://brickscout.com/en/)
- [brickowl.com](https://www.brickowl.com/)
- [bricklink.com](https://bricklink.com)
- [ebay.com](https://www.ebay.com/)
- [catawiki.com](https://www.catawiki.com/)

Here you can sell any minifigures you have and use the revenue to buy others, all the while enjoying the benefits (buyer and seller protection, market share, infrastructure) of an established site. Using these sites might not be straightforward for the first time, so be sure to read up on their own rules and customs, or ask around to learn what you must/should/could (not) do on them.

If, however, you mean "trading" rather as swapping, without involving money, be mindful that there can be huge differences in the value of a minifigure. Depending on age, condition, accessories, rarity and of course desirability, there can be a price range from under a dollar to hundreds of dollars for a single minifigure.

Comment: I was originally talking about swapping but, trading in say Ebay isn’t a bad idea either.

Comment: https://swapfig.com/

Comment: @Hugo That sounds like an upvote-worthy answer to me, care to make it into one? Or should I just add it to the list in mine with proper attribution to you?

Comment: @zovits You can just add it to your list so all the relevant informations are in the same answer ;)

Comment: @Hugo Thank you, I have incorporated your comment into the answer. If you have any experience with the platform, please share your opinion about it, as at the moment I have more questions than answers to its operating principles, methods and overall usefulness.

Comment: @zovits Honestly I haven't used this website before. I was looking for a website called minifigure swap as I have used this one in the past but unfortunattly it has shut down. I stumbled on swapfig.com while looking for the other one. If the concept is the same this mean you can create a list of figs you want to trade and a list of figs you're looking for. Once it's done you can search for potential trade and you'll see the people that match your search/offer. You can then propose an exchange. The other person as the possibility to accept or refuse the trade.

Comment: If he accept you have to exchange postal info and send the fig. When the fig is received you have to check a box in the trade process page and you can leave a comment. Same if the fig is never received. Like Bricklink, building a good reputation is necessary if you want to be trusted in making exchanges. Concerning the FAQ on their website, I noticed you can see the answer if you open the question in another tab.

Comment: @Hugo Thanks, I have added your remark to the answer. Since now you have contributed more to it than I did, I converted it to a community wiki to avoid unfairly profiting from your contributions.

Comment: @zovits Thanks a lot but I really don't mind about the points and stuff :) You can take them ;)

Comment: @Hugo I'm not doing it for the points either, and with a CW nobody gets points anyway :) Meanwhile it's simultaneously encouraging anyone to amend the list in the future - as these services are expected to come and go, like you have experienced.